# Is it possible to get a username form a VPN (L2TP/IPSec) connection?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I am currently maintaining web applications available from a secure network.  My users connect to the network within a VPN connection using L2TP/IPSec, to which they authenticate using their user id and password.  When they access the web application, they also have to authenticate again with the same user id and password.

Since they have authenticated once to the VPN already, is it possible for the application to verify their authentication status and get their identity from the VPN?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your VPN server and the capabilities of your web app. If your web app can access the VPN servers logs, current connections or API than yeah you might be able to set something up.

George